# Is it possible to create a round map frame in QGIS Map Composer to create circumpolar maps?

Tags: qgis, cartography, print-composer

Does anybody know if it's possible to create a round map frame in QGIS Map Composer to create circumpolar maps?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with QGIS native frame settings. But you can still clip your map with a circular polygon and style this polygon like a frame (a bit like [this](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/qPGhSyrkUV_ZAOCqB6yVtGMrcKVYAgQYbALz83Y2mq8bSKhEJW2zSd-TLZNxws1RK73Y1V-G9sw0q6r2Q005fzKWICWYvBWLGA-LQSh1rePt3Q51TGN4CVS0UsFVpA)).

Comment: ok, but then its getting difficult with adding coordinates around the round polygon which is still embedded in the rectangular mapframe....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's currently no out-of-the-box functionality for this in Print Composer. As a work-around, you can add graticules as a separate layer and label their end points, like here:

[image]

For a full how to, see https://anitagraser.com/2016/05/01/how-to-create-round-maps-in-print-composer/

[image]

(Example uses data from http://www.quantarctica.org/)

Comment: Is there possibilities to do circle maps on print composer without clipping layers? I have so many layers and if I do so I will be duplicated data unnecessarily.

Comment: @DiogoCaribé: Yes, as shown above, if you are ok with using a mask. Only downside of the mask is that you cannot have an automatic labeled grid like on the smaller overview map.

Comment: This only work when we have a map that all around is white. I really need a new map to composer that is able to became rounded.